Is there a possible way to use a specific project analysis results in a new project for the same src files?
I have some old coverity runs for some src files. I have copied those src files under new directory but src files hierarchy as well as files names are already the same. I want to start a new coverity project to analyze src files in their new directory (I preferably don't want to touch the old project) but somehow import the old analysis results (like the latest assignees for the defects, first detection dates or any old analysis results). Is there a way to do so ?
Note: I'm using Coverity 2023.06
Didn't try anything yet

If I understand correctly, what you want to happen will happen automatically when you run and commit a new analysis.
In the Coverity system, each issue reported by a particular analysis run is assigned a CID ("Coverity ID") based on relatively stable characteristics like the name of the checker that produced it and the name of the function it was found in.  Triage (meaning whether it is a false positive, who it is assigned to, when it was first discovered, etc.) is then associated with that CID, not the issue occurrence reported during a particular run.
When a new run is performed on the same or a similar code base, a similar set of issues will be reported.  Those issues whose stable characteristics match those of an already-reported issue will be assigned the same CID as that previous issue, and hence be associated with the same triage.
This sharing of triage happens regardless of the source file paths (although in certain circumstances, the file name without its path is included among the "stable characteristics"), and also across Coverity Connect streams (and hence projects).
The exception is if you create a new triage store and then make a new stream and associate it with that new store.  Each triage store has its own set of CIDs and associated triage information, so in that case the new analysis would not have its issues linked with the previous ones.
For more information, see the Coverity documentation sections:

Triaging issues, which explains the main triage user interface.

Managing triage stores, which explains the triage store feature.


